# Mixing latest Hibernate Search with Lucene 4

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

Anybody got a mix of the latest Hibernate Search (4.4.0.+)....

and Lucene 4 to work?  Is it possible?  Assuming too much has changed internally from Lucene 3 to 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible.  Hibernate Search 4.4 is intended to work with Lucene 3.6.

It appears that Lucene 4.X support is planned for [Hibernate Search 5.0](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1191)

Comment: Got that impress as well.  More of a shout in the dark if somebody had gone the extra mile to retrofit prior to HS 5.